# Wie schreibt man eine Abkürzung?

Tags: abbreviation

Ich habe verschiedene Arten für Abkürzungschreibung gesehen. Z.B:

- z. B.
- z.B.
- zb
- u.s.w.
- usw.

Alle Arten werden in großen Zeitungen benutzt. Wann verwendet man Punkte und Leerzeichen? Gibt es ein Unterschied? Welche Art ist "richtig"?

Comment: Was heißt hier richtig? Gemäß den aktuellen Regeln oder gemäß dem allgemeinen Gebrauch?

Comment: @bernd_k: Darum steht es _"richtig"_. Ich möchte gern eine Antwort, die vom Präskriptivismus _und_ Deskriptivismus erklärt.

Comment: Umformulierung: Darum steht hier "richtig".Ich hätte gerne eine Antwort die es vom präskriptiven und deskriptiven Standpunkt her erklärt.

Comment: @bernd_k: Danke schön!

Comment: "zB" ist auf jeden Fall sehr ungebräuchlich bis falsch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Abkürzung für "zum Beispiel" wird z. B. [laut](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/z__B_) [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zum_Beispiel) mit Leerzeichen verwendet:

> z. B.

Hier gilt folgende Regel: Abkürzungen, die nicht abgekürzt ausgesprochen werden, werden grundsätzlich mit Punkten abgekürzt. Wenn die Abkürzung mehrteilig ist, stehen Leerzeichen zwischen den Bestandteilen.

Weitere Beispiele:

- d. h. (das heißt)
- i. d. R. (in der Regel)

Das in der Frage erwähnte *usw.* ist eine Ausnahme. Es hat sich sich anstelle des eigentlich korrekten *u. s. w.* als Abkürzung für *und so weiter* durchgesetzt hat wie die lateinische Variante *etc.* für *et cetera*.

[Wikipedia hat hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abk%C3%BCrzung#Abk.C3.BCrzungen_mit_Punkt.2C_aber_ohne_Leerzeichen) noch einen Zusatz vermerkt:

> **Abkürzungen mit Punkt, aber ohne Leerzeichen**
>
> Die Abkürzungsweise mit Punkten, aber ohne Leerzeichen, ist veraltet. Es gibt aber drei Sonderfälle, in welchen dies weiterhin zulässig ist:
>
> - Sonderfall: Bei der Verwendung einer Festbreitenschrift (wie etwa bei einer Schreibmaschine) darf das Leerzeichen bei Abkürzungen entfallen. Bei der Verwendung einer Proportionalschrift gilt das fehlende Leerzeichen hingegen als falsch.
>     Beispiele: z.B., d.h., s.o., aber: z. B., d. h., s. o.
> - Sonderfall: Bei eingebürgerten Abkürzungen, die aus allgemeiner Gewohnheit oder aus Marketinggründen nicht der aktuellen Abkürzungsschreibweise angepasst wurden.
>     Beispiele: F.A.Z.
> - Sonderfall: Österreich; gemäß ÖNORM waren bei manchen Abkürzungen, wie jener von „zum Beispiel“, auch folgende Schreibweisen korrekt: zB und z.B. Nach der neuesten Ausgabe muss es jedoch so geschrieben werden: z. B.

Comment: Muss gestehen, dass ich mein ganzes Leben lang "z.B." geschrieben habe.

Comment: Danke. "z. B." war en Beispiel. Duden schreibt "und so weiter" als ["usw."](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/usw_), so Leerzeichen zu haben ist anscheinend keine regel.

Comment: usw. ist nicht mehrteilig -> u. s. w. (nicht üblich)

Comment: @splattne Danke sehr!

Comment: Habe meine Antwort noch mal erweitert. Der "usw."-Einwand ist durchaus berechtigt. Danke!

Comment: @splattne: dito. Ich verwende aber auch keine unterschiedlich langen Leerzeichen, also fällt das evtl. unter den 1. Sonderfall.

Comment: Das ist wirklich interessant, hätte schwören können, dass die Version ohne Leerzeichen richtig ist.

Answer (score 4):

Die Worte werden mit Punkten und Leerzeichen getrennt. Bei Leerzeichen gibt es aber das Problem, dass es zu Zeilenumbrüchen kommen kann, weswegen man, wenn möglich, ein schmales Leerzeichen verwendet. Das geht in Latex mit `\,` und im HTML mit `&#x202f;`.

Früher konnte man es auch ohne Leerzeichen schreiben, heute ist das nur in Ausnahmefällen möglich. Wenn man eine nichtproportionale Schriftart verwendet, kann es weiterhin ohne Leerzeichen geschrieben werden. Bei Verwendung einer proportionalen Schriftart ist es jedoch nicht zulässig.

Comment: Willkommen auf german.SE! Wenn man Regeln oder Standards anführt, ist es auf den Stack-Exchange-Seiten generell immer eine gute Idee, Quellen anzugeben - entweder in Form eines Links oder eines Zitats. Nicht daß du jetzt graben gehen *mußt* oder so, die Antwort ist völlig ok. Nur als Hinweis.

Comment: Danke. Ist es immer so? Ich habe die Frage verbessert.

Comment: Ist bei HTML nicht ein &nbsp; als 'non breaking space' die Technik, einen Umbruch dort zu verhindern, oder sind beide äquivalent, d.h. das &nbsp; auch schmal, oder nur das schmale implizit auch umbruchabhold?

Comment: Das non-breaking space in HTML heißt nur, dass es keinen Zeilenumbruch erzwingt, nicht, dass keiner möglich ist. Es erhält den Zeichenfluss, ermöglicht dem Browser aber bei Bedarf durch einen Zeilenumbruch ersetzt zu werden.

Comment: Nein. &nbsp; ist eben genau dazu da, einen Zeilenumbruch zu verhindern. So ist es auch beim W3C definiert: "A common character entity used in HTML is the non-breaking space: &nbsp; A non-breaking space is a space that will not break into a new line." http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 1):

Der [Wikipedia-Artikel zum Thema](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abk%C3%BCrzung) ist eigentlich recht ausführlich und gut erklärt.

Das Problem mit dem Leerzeichen in Abkürzungen hat Klaus ja schon angesprochen:

- Es sieht hässlich aus: „z. B.“ – insbesondere mit einer Festbreitenschrift: „`z. B.`“
- Es kann zu einem noch hässlicheren Umbruch führen: z.
  B.

Aus diesem Grund sollte *nie* ein normales Leerzeichen verwendet werden. Sondern (in absteigender Präferenz):

1. Ein [schmales geschütztes Leerzeichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmales_Leerzeichen) (U+202F)": „z. B.“
2. Ein [(normales) geschütztes Leerzeichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesch%C3%BCtztes_Leerzeichen) (U+00A0): „z. B.“
3. (Zur Not!) Ein schmales Leerzeichen (U+2009): „z. B.“
4. (Zur Not! – und in Festbreitenschriften) kein Leerzeichen, also „z.B.“

Leider ist das schmale geschützte Leerzeichen (die „korrekteste” Wahl) noch kaum unterstützt (d.h. es existiert in nur sehr wenigen Schriftarten), daher muss meistens auf eine der Alternativen ausgewichen werden.

Answer (score 0):

Ich empfinde das aber als typografische Konvention und nicht als Frage der Rechtschreibung.

Hier werden ältere Leute einfach weiter ihren Gewohnheiten folgen und sich von Normen und Duden nicht beeindrucken lassen.

Wenn man alles normen will, sollte man bei Handy Ladegeräten (charger for mobile phones) anfangen und nicht bei solchen Nebensächlichkeiten.

Ich schreibe weiterhin z.B. .

Comment: Ich würde ja sagen, Recht hast Du, zu schreiben wie Dir die Tastatur gewachsen ist, aber die Frage ist ja nun, wie es richtig ist. Das interessiert mich auch, obwohl ich zu bequem bin groß zwischen unterschiedlichen Leerzeichen oder zw. Bindestrich, Minus, Trennstrich und Gedankenstrich zu unterscheiden, wenn ich schreibe. Aber wegen der automatischen Umbrüche der Textverarbeitungen bin ich auch von anfänglichen, logischeren Leerzeichen zw. z. B. zum Beispiel abgekommen, und setze lieber z.B. - das wird automatisch nicht getrennt, und läßt sich m.E. gut lesen, und darauf kommt es ja an.